# Why doesn't my Zapier Integration Dynamic Field work?

Tags: zapier

I have a simple zapier integration built and it works perfectly. However, I'm adding dynamic fields. Again it all seems to work perfectly when I test the zap. My dynamic form fields appear just as I expected.

The problem is sending the value of those dynamic forms to my API. I am using the zapier console and when I configure the API request I am using the following:

Where `body['custom_fields']` is supposed to send all my dynamic fields or even all of the fields. But when it hits my API `custom_fields` parameter is blank.

```js
const options = {
  url: 'https://example_url/endpoint',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.auth_token}`
  },
  body: {
    'email': bundle.inputData.email,
    'custom_fields': bundle.inputData

    /**
      I've tried the following with no luck:

     'custom_fields': bundle.inputData.fields
     'custom_fields': bundle.inputData.undefined
     'custom_fields': bundle.inputData
    */
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = response.json;

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results;
  });
```

Comment: can you update your question to include your `inputFields` and/or dynamic field generation code? `bundle.inputData` should have everything coming into the zap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after a few days, it's the simplest answer.

Obviously an object can't be sent over params.

so instead of having

```
'custom_fields': bundle.inputData
```

I just add the whole object to the params and it takes care of all keys and values

```
params: bundle.inputData
```

Here is the full body

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://apiendpoint.com',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.auth_token}`
  },
  params: bundle.inputData,

}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = response.json;

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator `...bundle.inputData` like explained in the doc:

https://platform.zapier.com/docs/input-designer#how-to-include-dynamic-fields-in-api-calls

```js
const options = {
  url: 'https://example_url/endpoint',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.auth_token}`
  },
  body: { ...bundle.inputData }
}
```

You can even namespace your request data like that:

```js
  body: {
    request: { ...bundle.inputData }
  }
```

NB : the spread operator raises a syntax error in Zapier code editor, but it works.